# Which dua after wudhu is correct?

Tags: hadith, sunni, dua, wudu, hanafi

After performing wudhu, which dua are you supposed to recite?  I have been researching this, and have found 2 slightly different variations.

Which variation is correct according to the sunni > hanafi belief system?

This one?
[image]

Or this one?
[image]

I am after the **sunni > hanafi view**.

I appoligize for my bad image editing skills, the texts were over multiple pages, and I removed the translations from under the text

Answer (score 1):

> أَشْهَدُ أَنْ لَا إِلَهَ إلَّا اللهُ وَحْدَهُ لَا شَرِيكَ لَهُ، وَأَشْهَدُ أَنَّ مُحَمَّداً عَبْدُهُ وَرَسُولُهُ
>
> "Ash-hadu "an la "ilaha "illallahu wahdahu la sharika lahu wa "ash-hadu "anna Muhammadan 'abduhu wa Rasuluhu. -Muslim 1/209

I bear witness that none has the right to be worshipped but Allah alone, Who has no partner; and I bear witness that Muhammad is His slave and His Messenger.

> اللَّهُمَّ اجْعَلْنِي مِنَ التَّوَّابِينَ وَاجْعَلْنِي مِنَ الْمُتَطَهِّرِينَ
>
> Allahummaj 'alni minat-tawwabina waj'alni minal-mutatahhirin.

O Allah, make me among those who turn to You in repentance, and make me among those who are purified.

> سُبْحَانَكَ اللَّهُمَّ وَبِحَمْدِكَ، أَشْهَدُ أَنْ لَا إِلَهَ إِلَّا أَنْتَ، أَسْتَغْفِرُكَ وَأَتُوبُ إِلَيْكَ
>
> Subhanaka Allahumma wa bihamdika, "ash-hadu "an la "ilaha "illa "Anta, 'astaghfiruka wa 'atubu 'ilayk.

Glory is to You, O Allah, and praise; I bear witness that there is none worthy of worship but You. I seek Your forgiveness and turn to You in repentance.

Comment: Assalamu alaikum...Please read the question carefully... [How do I write a good answer?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

I follow Hanafi way and my answer is as follows:

I have come accross two ways for the same, both have been discussed here,
The `tareeqah` which was taught to us by our `Ulemah-e-deen` is such that just after finishing your `wudhu`, You read

[image]

then, You recite the `du'a`

[image]

Then take the water and stand up and drink some, as this is cure for the illnesses.
Then look towards the sky and pray;

## سُبْحَانَكَ اللَّهُمَّ وَبِحَمْدِكَ أَشْهَدُ أَنْ لَا إِلَهَ إِلَّا أَنْتَ أَسْتَغْفِرُكَ وَأَتُوبَ إِلَيْكَ

'Subhanaka Allahumma Wa Behamdika Ashhadu An La ilaha illa Anta Astagfiruka Wa Atoobo ilaik' Also recite verses of `Surah Al-Qadr`.

2) The ablution (Wuzu) is complete and so pray this Dua,

> 'Allahummajalni Minattawwabeena Waj'alni Minal Mutahhireen'

Then take the water and stand up and drink some, as this is cure for the illnesses.

Then look towards the sky and pray;

> 'Subhanaka Allahumma Wa Behamdika Ashhadu An La ilaha illa Anta Astagfiruka Wa Atoobo ilaik' Also pray the Kalima Shahaadat and Sura Inna Anzalna.

May Allah forgive any mistake I would have made in answering this question and give us `Hidayat` for following the straight path.

Aameen!! bijahinn sayyidil mursaleen Salallahu alaihi wa sallam